# Integral over Boole step function does not evaluate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, symbolic

I have a uniform probability distribution in polar coordinates for `r`as well as `phi`. To get the marginal distribution as a function of `x`, I have to intgrate:

```
r[x_, y_] := Sqrt[x^2 + y^2];
p[x_, y_] := ArcTan[x, y];

G[r_, p_] := 
1/(b - a)*1/(d - c)*Boole[r - a >= 0]*Boole[b - r >= 0]*
Boole[p - c >= 0]*Boole[d - p >= 0]

Integrate[G[r[x, y], p[x, y]]/r[x, y], {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
Assumptions -> {a > 0, b > 0, b > a, c > 0, d > 0, d > c, 
Element[x, Reals], Element[y, Reals]}]
```

However, this integral does not evaluate. If I leave out the condition on the angle `p` in the definition of `G`, everything works fine. Does the integral simple get to complicated or can this be solved somehow?

Comment: What does convince you that there should exist a closed form for the integral?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher. I do not know that. But would it be possible for Mathematica to formulate cases depending on x,a,b,c,d and express the `Boole` functions as integral boundaries?

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher My line of though was as follows: `1/Sqrt[x^2+y^2]` can be solved. The Boolean functions can be transferred to the boundaries. Thus, the integral should have a closed form on different intervals of x.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure Mathematica can solve this integral, but I guess your main question is about `Boole`. You can replace the boolean ranges you used with a call to `HeavisideTheta`. This function is closely related to `DiracDelta` and was made for the usage in integrals. You should probably read more about distributions and the [Dirac delta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function) in particular.

Anyway, compare these:

```
Plot[Boole[x > 3], {x, -5, 5}]
Plot[HeavisideTheta[x - 3], {x, -5, 5}]
```

or

```
Plot[Boole[1 < x < 3], {x, -5, 5}]
Plot[HeavisideTheta[x - 1] - HeavisideTheta[x - 3], {x, -5, 5}]
```

And to give an example and show these two are equivalent

```
With[{
  i1 = Integrate[Sin[x]*(HeavisideTheta[x] - HeavisideTheta[x - Pi]), x],
  i2 = Integrate[Sin[x]*Boole[0 < x < Pi], x]},
 Plot[{i1, i2}, {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[.015], Yellow}]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The difference in the antiderivatives is that `Boole` results in a `Piecewise` function, while `HeavisideTheta` gives a closed form.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I used `HeavisideTheta` before, which took too long to evaluate even without the last two angular parts, while `Boole` works if I leave out the angle condition. I would be fine with a piecewise function as a closed form might not exist but I do not know how to get this piecewise function.